# Schedulable Batch Apex class

Tags: apex, batch

```
global void execute(SchedulableContext cc) {
    BatchApexClass batchObject = new BatchApexClass();
    Database.executeBatch(batchObject,10) ;
}
```

What is the meaning for 10 in the syntax "`Database.executeBatch(batchObject,10)`"?
Is that the total batch size or etc.,?

Comment: Note that, as per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_access_modifiers.htm#modifier_global), you should try to avoid using the "global" keyword. It is no longer mandated for most cases and is only needed if the class/method must be exposed across "app" (e.g. package) boundaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, `Database's` `executeBatch` method has two overloads

- One which takes only one parameter i.e. instance of the batch class and does not take scope as parameter and processes the records with default batch size of 200.
- Other which takes two parameters, first the `instance` of the batch class and second the `scope` variable i.e. an `integer` which specifies the number of records to be passed into the `execute` method for batch processing.

So in your example, its the second overload which will pass 10 records at a time to `execute` method of batch class for processing. If you have 100 records in all to be processed and if you have set your batch size as 10, your records would be split in 100/10 i.e. 10 batches i.e. `execute` method will run 10 times.

The default size of the scope if not specified is 200 and the maximum value it can have is 2000.

Excerpt from Salesforce [Database](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm) class documentation

> The value for scope must be greater than 0.
>
> If the start method of the batch class returns a
>   Database.QueryLocator, the scope parameter of Database.executeBatch
>   can have a maximum value of 2,000. If set to a higher value,
>   Salesforce chunks the records returned by the QueryLocator into
>   smaller batches of up to 200 records. If the start method of the batch
>   class returns an iterable, the scope parameter value has no upper
>   limit; however, if you use a very high number, you could run into
>   other limits.
>
> Apex governor limits are reset for each execution of execute.
>
> For more information, see [Using Batch
>   Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm).

You can go through Invoking a batch apex section of [Asynchronous Apex](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/asynchronous_apex/async_apex_batch) trailhead module to get more information on this.

Comment: Excellent @Vijay....So if i have 100 records it will have 10 batches in my case since i limited it to handle 10 reccords at a time? am i right or still confused

Comment: @VijayGanji, you have a typo in last comment ("1000/10" should be "100/10").

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Vijay ....Appreciate the help much..!✌

Comment: Thanks @PhilW, I can't edit the comments, so deleted it and included that as an example in the answer itself :)